# How to document private elements in scaladoc with scala-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

I'm trying to generate Scaladoc for my code with the scala-maven-plugin 3.0.2 (Scala Version 2.9.2). When I use

```
mvn scala:doc
```

then I don't get documentation for the private types and elements of my **Scala** code. I checked with the plugin documentation, but I can't find an option for that.

Strangely, the scaladoc plugin does generate documentation for the private elements of my **Java** code. But because it doesn't generate documentation for the HTML comments of the Java code, this is pretty useless.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't have any clue but... what is the point of providing public documentation for a private field?

Comment: Providing readable documentation for the future me and other team members, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you haven't miss it. I had done similar research few weeks ago and also didn't find it.